# Should read-the-manual questions be closed, or even answered?

Tags: discussion

Case in point: [Can I install an under-counter electric hot water tank on it’s side rather than vertically?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/287264/35141)

This type of question is so easily answered that it reflects lack of effort on the part of the asker, as well as a failure of basic due diligence in the project itself. ("Lack of effort" is a thing on Stack Overflow.)

Should we close these? If so, under what reason?

Should they be answered? (This is more of a philosophical question relating to one's response to laziness or almost deliberate ignorance.)

Answer (score 3):

As the first one to answer that question, I suppose I should answer here too.

When I saw the question, my first thought was RTFM. Which I did and answered based on that. Looking at the timing of the comments, I have a hunch OP didn't read the manual until after I posted the link, even though it sounds like he has the unit in hand and therefore should have a printed manual - i.e., no need to search for it online. And yet, still questioning it:

*Manual says vertically but it is a sealed 4 gallon tank. I don’t know why it can’t?*

So it sounds like a combination of not doing due diligence combined with not wanting to believe the manufacturer's instructions - i.e., wishful thinking.

When I searched for the answer in the manual I didn't know if I would find an answer that easily, but in this case it really was that easy. But once I did that search, I actually had the answer and felt it made sense to post it.

Now if we had Close Reasons for:

- RTFM (which would work here)
- Are you absolutely crazy, you'll burn your house down! (which would work for a lot of oddball electrical questions)
- Sorry, that's a rental, call a professional.

then a lot more questions would get closed really quickly.

Comment: +10,000 for your suggested close reasons!!